# NSDate and AVPlayerItem.currentTime

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, avplayer

i know there are a lot of topics, but i can´t find a solution for my problem.

i have an AVPlayerItem and i want the currentTime-property (CMTime) convert to a readable format for my music player.

this is my code:

```
NSDate *seconds = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:CMTimeGetSeconds(self.playerItem.currentTime)];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

self.currentTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [timeFormatter stringFromDate:seconds]];
```

it works but it adds 1 hour to the played Time. how can i subtract that hour?

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code,

swift code:

delclare

```
var playerVal = AVPlayer()
```

then call below method where you want,

```
func updateTime() {

        let currentTime = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(playerVal.currentTime()))
        let minutes = currentTime/60
        let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60

        startValue.text = NSString(format: "%.2f:%.2f", minutes,seconds) as String

    }
```

objective-C code:

delclare

```
AVPlayer playerVal;
```

then call below method where you want,

```
- (void)updateTime {
    Float currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds([playerVal currentTime]);
    Float minutes = currentTime/60;
    Float seconds = (currentTime - minutes) * 60;
    startValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f:%.2f", minutes,seconds];
}
```

its working for me, hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

thx, i refined it a bit:

```
float currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds([self.audioStreamPlayer currentTime]);

int seconds = (int) currentTime;
int minutes = (int) currentTime/60;
int hours = (int) ((currentTime/60)/60);

NSString *hoursString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",hours];
NSString *minutesString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",minutes];
NSString *secondsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seconds % 60];

if (hoursString.length == 1) {
    hoursString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", hours];
}
if (minutesString.length == 1) {
    minutesString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",minutes];
}
if (secondsString.length == 1) {
    secondsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", seconds % 60];
}



self.currentTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:%@", hoursString, minutesString, secondsString];
```

works!